# How to extract features with different formats in a text file in python?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, feature-extraction, text-extraction

i have several text files of company invoices which have different kinds of Date formats

`dd/mm/yyyy`

`mm:dd:yy`

`dd,monthname,yy`

`yearname,monthname,dd`

and so on.
Theres lots of unique patterns that cant be listed here.

Problem is i have been using a mix of regex and (mostly) if else string matching to find out these dates but im sure there's a better way to identify them instead of hardcoding the program to find different patterns

I would also like to extract other features like 'TOTAL' amount which also has formats like

Total
$123

Total $123

$123
Total

$123 Total

Here are some example text files

```
Demo Company INVOICE
Demo Company Phone : 141-222-3333 Invoice# 1024
1234 Main Street Fax: 222-3984444 Account# C1000
Ashland, KY 41102 Email : sales@example.com 
Date 01-08-2009
Due By 02-05-2009
‘Subtotal $212.44
Tax $1.25
Total $213.69
Balance Due $213.69
```

```
SAMPLE PURCHASE ORDER
ToNGE
Purchase Order Number 2
FROM: Purchase Order Date 6:15:2
Your Company
1122 Cherry Lane
San Diego, CA 92176
1 | MH1000 | MATHOIST STORAGE SYSTEMFOR (@)45°x $8920.00 | $8,920.00
MATS (see product description)
1 [NA Mat Hoist Voltage??? 208V, 230V or 460V Nec Nec
6 |cL7 CL-7 UNIT CLAMP
SA8.75 $292.50
```

```
123 Anywhere St.
Some City, CA 91000
Phone (555) 555-1212 Fax (555) 555-5555
P.O. NUMBER: 1234
P.O. DATE: 4/15/13
SUBTOTAL $3000
SALES TAX $s 240
TOTAL $3240
```

Heres the code i am using for date extraction and total extraction

```
def extractdate():
    with open(inpf, "r") as ifile:
        for line in ifile:
            if line.startswith("DATE"):
                print(next(ifile, '').strip())
            elif line.startswith("P.O. DATE"):
                if "P.O. DATE" in line:
                    # print(line)
                    print('')
            elif str("Date") in line:
                    # print(line)
                    print('')
            elif str("date")in line:
                    # print(line)
                    print('')
```

```
def totalamount():
    with open(inpf, "r") as ifile:
        for line in ifile:
            if 'TOTAL' in line or 'Total' in line:
                s = ""
                for i in range(len(line)):
                    if line[i].isdigit():
                        s += line[i]
                    elif not line[i].isdigit() and line[i-1].isdigit():
                        break
```

Is there any way i can use machine learning and train a model to extract these features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet a problem for NLP.  You have two categories of data to find: date and total money.  There are many references for finding and parsing various date-time formats; you'll need to research those, depending on the parsing form you want to use.  Regular expressions or built-in parsing packages are usually the easiest.

The other one is simple: you're looking for a line with the word "total" and a '$'.  When both of those exist in the line, simply grab the decimal amount adjacent to the '$'.

Given that these are two problems with known solutions, using machine learning is a bit of overkill.